# Regex for finding http and https url from a string

Tags: java, regex

I have a string which contains multiple url starting from http and https I need to fetch all those url and put into a list.

I have tried below code.

```
List<String> httpLinksList = new ArrayList<>();

String hyperlinkRegex = "((http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?(([a-zA-Z0-9-]){2,}\.){1,4}([a-zA-Z]){2,6}(\/([a-zA-Z-_\/\.0-9#:?=&;,]*)?)?)";
```

String synopsis = "This is http://stackoverflow.com/questions and  https://test.com/method?param=wasd The code below catches all urls in text and returns urls in list";

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(hyperlinkRegex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(synopsis);
    while(matcher.find()){
        System.out.println(matcher.find()+"  "+matcher.group(1)+"  "+matcher.groupCount()+"  "+matcher.group(2));

        httpLinksList.add(matcher.group());
    }

    System.out.println(httpLinksList);
```

I need below result 
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions,
https://test.com/method?param=wasd]
But getting below output
[https://test.com/method?param=wasd]

Comment: try this `((http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?(([a-zA-Z0-9-]){2,}.){1,4}([a-zA-Z]){2,6}(\/([a-zA-Z-_\/.0-9#:?=&;,]*)?)?)`

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to pull anything which is after http(s) and keep going untill you hit a white space? Or are you doing some specific validation as well?

Comment: @Vishal It is not returning the expected result

Comment: @npinti Yes it will be simpler in that case. I am working on that regex.

Comment: Check this https://regex101.com/r/pqxTDU/1/

Comment: I've pasted the regex in a regex101.com and it seems to work. One thing I have noticed is this: `[a-zA-Z-_\/\.0-9#:?=&;,]` The `-` in square brackets denotes **character ranges**, you would need to put it at the end, like so: `[a-zA-Z_\/\.0-9#:?=&;,-]`

Comment: check that [link](https://regex101.com/r/pqxTDU/1/) again (updated it), I have pasted your whole sentence and it will match now your requirements. regex is `((http:\/\/|https:\/\/)(([a-zA-Z0-9-]){2,}.){1,4}([a-zA-Z]){2,6}(\/([a-zA-Z-_\/.0-9#:?=&;,]*)?)+)`

Comment: Sorry, the link is https://regex101.com/r/pqxTDU/2/. I missed the '2'

Comment: @vishal I am getting 1 result in output i.e last link "https://test.com/method?param=wasd". Is it matching the last pattern in the string ?
or it is some functionality of matcher.find() method which is restricting all result.

Comment: By the way your pattern will not detect some valid URLs like URLs with cyrillic or Hiragana characters. Probably your best bet is to tokenize string into tokens (or IndexOf-based variant :-))

Comment: Try `https?://\S+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This regex will match all the valid urls, including FTP and other**

```
String urlRegex = "((https?|ftp|gopher|telnet|file):((//)|(\\\\))+[\\w\\d:#@%/;$()~_?\\+-=\\\\\\.&]*)";
```

---

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class xmlValue {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
String text = "This is http://stackoverflow.com/questions and https://test.com/method?param=wasd The code below catches all urls in text and returns urls in list";
        System.out.println(extractUrls(text));
    }

    public static List<String> extractUrls(String text)
    {
        List<String> containedUrls = new ArrayList<String>();
        String urlRegex = "((https?|ftp|gopher|telnet|file):((//)|(\\\\))+[\\w\\d:#@%/;$()~_?\\+-=\\\\\\.&]*)";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(urlRegex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher urlMatcher = pattern.matcher(text);

        while (urlMatcher.find())
        {
            containedUrls.add(text.substring(urlMatcher.start(0),
                    urlMatcher.end(0)));
        }

        return containedUrls;
    }
}
```

**Output**:

> [http://stackoverflow.com/questions,
>   https://test.com/method?param=wasd]

**credits @BullyWiiPlaza**

Answer (score 1):

So I know this is not exactly what you asked since you are specifically looking for `regex`, but I thought this would fun to try out with an `indexOf` variant.  I will leave it here as an alternative to the regex someone comes up with:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
   String synopsis = "This is http://stackoverflow.com/questions and https://test.com/method?param=wasd The code below catches all urls in text and returns urls in list";

    ArrayList<String> list = splitUrl(synopsis);
    for (String s : list) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}

public static ArrayList<String> splitUrl(String s) 
{
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    int spaceIndex = 0;
    while (true) {
        int httpIndex = s.indexOf("http", spaceIndex);
        if (httpIndex < 0) {
            break;
        }

        spaceIndex = s.indexOf(" ", httpIndex);
        if (spaceIndex < 0) {
            list.add(s.substring(httpIndex));
            break;
        }
        else {
            list.add(s.substring(httpIndex, spaceIndex));
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

All the logic is contained in the `splitUrl(String s)` method, it takes in a `String` as a parameter and outputs the `ArrayList<String>` of all the split urls.

It first searches for the index of any `http` and then the first space that occurs after the url and substrings the difference.  It then uses the space it found as the second parameter in `indexOf(String, int)` to start searching the `String` beginning after the http that was already found so it does not repeat the same ones.

Additionally a case had to be made when the `http` is the final part of the `String` as there is no space afterward.  This is done when the `indexOf` the space returns negative, I use `substring(int)` instead of `substring(int, int)` which will take the current location and substring the *rest* of the String.

The loop ends when either `indexOf` returns with a negative, though if the space returns negative it does that final `substring` operation before the `break`.

**Output:**

> http://stackoverflow.com/questions
>
> https://test.com/method?param=wasd

**Note:**  As someone mentioned in the comments too, this implementation will work with non-Latin characters such as Hiragana too, which could be an advantage over regex.

Comment: thanks for details example. I have implemented the same using StringTokenizer as suggested by Ivkin Igor

Comment: Great, your answer is a voice of mind :) That said, you had a problem and decided to solve it using regexp, well, you have two problems now. Your solution actually requires some tweaks, for example it doesn't count cases like "(http://example.com)" or when it's line break or other white-space character (not a space) but it is definitely a move in a right direction!!

Comment: @Ivkin Igor Are you referring to my solution or his comment?  For my solution I just assumed the format of the `String` would be what he provided, for example no newlines and specifically looking for only `http` or `https`.

Comment: @Nexevis, yes, I referred your solution! In general it's completely ok and available to tweak with any additional limitations.